# Why doesn't CI convert count statement to an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter, count

I'm trying to make it so that you can view the number of rows of something on my website, I converted the result into an array and then foreached it in the view, yet it calls the argument invalid.

As I said, I've tried the usual, passing on the data from the model to the controller and then to the view. I tried returning `$query->num_rows();` as well as a `count_all_results` back to the controller array for it to be used in the view, both are invalid.

> controller.php

```
  $this->load->model('Main');
  $data = array(
    'getapps' => $this->Main->countapps()
  );
  $this->load->view('header', $data);
```

> view.php

```
<?php foreach($getapps as $apps) {
?>

<a href="http://localhost/Dir/index.php/Controller/Apps" class="a-m" id="a-m-id">apps <strong><?php echo $apps; ?></strong></a>

<?php }
?>
```

> model.php

```
public function countapps() {

$this->db->where('usedby', $_SESSION['uid']);
$this->db->get_where('apps', 'appstatus', 'Used');
$stmt = $this->db->count_all_results();

  return $stmt;
}
```

What I expect to happen is for the view to display the number of rows, instead it tells me that the foreach argument is invalidly supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CI `$this->db->count_all_results()` substitutes `$this->db->get()` in a database query. Therefore you cannot use `$this->db->get_where()` and `$this->db->count_all_results()` at the same time, use `num_rows()` instead.

write your model function like this:

```
public function countapps() {

 $query=$this->db->where('usedby', $_SESSION['uid'])
                 ->get_where('apps', 'appstatus', 'Used');
  $stmt = $query->num_rows();

  return $stmt;
}
```

you could change in your controller to a shorter:

```
$data['getapps'] => $this->Main->countapps();
```

Then in your view, you don't need to use `foreach()`  as $data['getapps'] is not an array but a number. You can output it in the view simply like

```
echo $getapps;
```

Comment: it throws this error: `Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::num_rows()`

Comment: Yeah, I added that, now the error is `Call to a member function num_rows() on array`

Comment: @frogman578 sorry mixed something up, now it's correct, in order to use num_rows(), you need to have a query result first...

Comment: that's were I was at first, the invalid `foreach` argument

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195031/discussion-between-frogman578-and-vickel).